# FullCalendar conflict on agendaWeek & agendaDay

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I configured a calendar that has AgendaDay and AgendaWeek on the same page.
anything working fine on both view, but by some small changes on Resources.

For Day I loaded the list of teacher and show them as the column, but if I want to work on week view, I should remove the Resource codes. That after this change the agenda week will work as well.

As you see by this method just one of them will be working at the same time.

**I use FullCalendar v3**
**Resource callback function**

```
resources: function(callback){
  jQuery('input[name="start"]').val($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start.format());
  jQuery('input[name="end"]').val($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end.format());
  $.ajax({
    url: resourcesCallback,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    data: jQuery('.calendar_filter_form').serialize(),
    error: function() {
      // alert('Oops! Try again.');
    },
    success: function(response){
      callback(response);
    }
  });
}
```

So how I can set it to load resource just when it is AgendaDay and ignore it on AgendaWeek?

This is a demo that I try to handle more dynamic.
https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/QWLvypO?editors=0010

The output that I have:
[image]
[image]

> **Update the question**

As I checked there is no issue with resource call back. Actually, the issue is with calendar configurations.
1- `groupByResource: true`
2- `groupByDateAndResource: true`

When I use both as true, the agenda Day shows data grouped in the correct format, not on AgendaWeek.
The code pen demo https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/ExYXWer?editors=0010

there you can change `groupByDateAndResource` to false by this switching the grouping will change and become based on instructor and days( in demo looks better.)

> **Main Issue:** I need to change the configuration for Agenda Day and Agenda Week specifically, In my case, I need to use groupByDateAndResource: True and groupByResource: true for Agenda Day but these two items should be false for Agenda Week on the same page.

Comment: _"how I can set it to load resource just when it is AgendaDay and ignore it on AgendaWeek"_ ...your CodePen is already doing that. The resources appear on the day view, and they do not appear on the week view. According to your question, that's what you wanted. The CodePen does not produce the output shown in your screenshot. So please, what's the problem? I can't understand what you need our help with. Can you explain more? Thanks.

Comment: I use a dynamic calendar that will update with navigation, the Code Pen sample is what I want and simply I can apply it, I want to switch between AgendaDay and AgendaWeek. By each switch the data will refresh, resources and events will Refetch. But this process breaks AgendaWeek, to fix that I need to remove Resource callback function but by this change, the AgendaDay will not work.

Comment: Totally the configuration is fine, just with Resources for AgendaDay and with out Resources for Agenda Week.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, why do you need to refresh the resources list every time you change the view? Does it not stay the same in all cases?

Comment: No, I have some filter that applied on resources and this filter will effect by navigation on the date and an on click function. That I refetch data with this code `          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
`

Comment: Ok. I made a new version of your CodePen using a callback with the same structure as shown in your question and I still can't make it "break" in any way: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/qBWmGmN?editors=1010 . Are you able to adapt that CodePen again to reproduce the issue you're describing? Maybe it's because in the demo it doesn't actually change the resources which are delivered...is that the critical factor?

Comment: @ADyson I reproduce the issue with my system data, and now I got that issue is with 1- groupByResource: true 2- groupByDateAndResource: true. I update my question please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I checked there is no issue with resource call back. Actually, the issue is with calendar configurations.

```
1- groupByResource: true 

2- groupByDateAndResource: true
```

So I need to use `groupByDateAndResource: True` and `groupByResource: true` for Agenda Day but these two items should be `false` for Agenda Week on the same page.

**So I do that with views option**
https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/mdbwmdO?editors=0010

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    defaultView: "agendaDay",
    views: {
      week: {
        groupByResource: false,
        groupByDateAndResource: false,
      },
      day: {
        groupByResource: true,
        groupByDateAndResource: true,
      },
    },
    ...
  });
```